# MS Excel data validator does not accept call to the custom macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, data-validation

I have the working VB macro that validates the content. It takes two string parameters (cell value and regular expression) and returns either True or False. It uses `CreateObject("VBscript.regexp")` internally.

I need to use this macro to validate the cell. When I try to set it as a custom validator the way

```
=Rex(E2, "\d{1,2}\:\d{2}")
```

where Rex is my function defined on the same spread sheet (Alt-F11 and type) and E2 is a cell I am trying to validate, I get the message "A named range you specified cannot be found".

If I insert the same function anywhere else on the same spreadsheet (say at the top corner cell A1):

```
=Rex(E2, "\d{1,2}\:\d{2}")
```

the it shows me nicely `TRUE` if the cell E2 correct the right value like `15:07` and `FALSE` if it does not like `15xx` - half solved but really not till the end. I really need to integrate my validator in a standard way.

I am using MS Excel 2010. The macro itself is

```
Public Function Rex(ByVal vsStringIn As String, ByVal vsPattern As String) As Boolean
    Dim objRegEx As Object
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBscript.regexp")

    objRegEx.Global = True
    objRegEx.Pattern = vsPattern

    Rex = objRegEx.Test(vsStringIn)
    Set objRegEx = Nothing
End Function
```

And the problem looks like

[image: MS Excel validator problem]

Comment: Can you share the code of your UDF?

Comment: Surely I can, it is very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem. Seems like UDFs don't always work in Data Validation! :-(

Following alternatives:

- Use Conditional Formatting instead and simply highlight any wrong value
- Use a normal Excel formula instead of your regex to do the validation. In your case,

  ```
  =IFERROR(IF(SEARCH(":",D3),AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(D3,SEARCH(":",D3)-1))),ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(D3,LEN(D3)-SEARCH(":",D3))))),FALSE),FALSE)
  ```

  will do the job. Not nice, but at least functional! ;-)

Side note: neither your UDF nor the above formula will work, if the value to be be checked is a number (with the Time format) and not a string!

Comment: Conditional formatting probably would work for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a old question, but I don't want to duplicate the question.

Solution: You can apply the UDF formula in a different cell, and then use that value in the Data Validation. You can hide the temporary value by just changing the color to white.

For more information:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/160523